# Expanding beamer arguments

Tags: beamer, expansion

I have created a new command that takes beamer-arguments (<...>), but I'm not able to pass them on. I suppose it's a \expandafter problem. Does anyone have a clue?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys{/mypgf/.cd, arg/.store in = \arg}

\newcommand<>\img[2][]{
    \pgfkeys{/mypgf/.cd, #1}

    {
        \def\options{} % set options to something useful based on #1

        % This works:
        \expandafter\includegraphics\expandafter[\options]{#2}

        % But not when I try to add the beamer argument:
        \expandafter\includegraphics#3\expandafter[\options]{#2}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\img<2-4>[arg=val]{example-image}

\end{document}
```

Comment: do you intend the macro to insert a paragraph break before image? (all the white space in the definition has an effect)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\expandafter\includegraphics#3\expandafter[\options]{#2}
```

the first `\expandafter` will expand the first token (only) of `#3` but that is `<` so nothing expands.  I think you intended

```
\def\foo{\includegraphics#3}%
\expandafter\foo\expandafter[\options]{#2}%
```

Comment: Perfect! Do you know why it isn't possible to do `\expandafter{\includegraphics#3}\expandafter[\options]{#2}`?

Comment: `\expandafter{\includegraphics` expands the first token after the `{` (which would be `\includegraphics` so it is effectively a no-op as `{` is not expandable so it is the same as `{\includegraphics` either way `\includegraphics` is the first thing to expand.